# VSTest configuration in TFS 2015 for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: build, tfs-2015, vstest, visual-studio-2017, vnext

I am having problems configuring VSTest task in TFS 2015 vNext build definition to run with Visual Studio 2017.

Selecting "Latest" in VSTest version drop down list does not work for VS2017. I found some posts in forums describing to provide specific location of VSTest, that would probably work. Unfortunately, I do not have this option:

[VSTest Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3g4zh.jpg)

Does anybody have an idea how to get it work?

Regards,
WHBonney

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Visual Studio Test task of TFS 2017, it has the option to specific location of `vstest.console.exe`. In TFS 2015, the Visual Studio Test step is in an old version. You could upgrade to TFS 2017 to specify test version in Visual Studio Test step.

Or as a workaround, the source code of the newest version step is at this site: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/VsTest. You could download the source code and upload it to TFS 2015 as a custom build task.

You could use [tfx-cli command](https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli/blob/master/docs/buildtasks.md) to upload a custom task. For TFS 2015, use `tfx login --auth-type basic` to login before upload.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! You confirm my worry...
Upgrading to TFS2017 is - for many reasons - not an option, at least not a fast one. Maybe we have to go with the custom task...

Comment: @WHBonney Could you please mark it as the answer for this issue. It will be beneficial for other communities who have similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

> I am having problems configuring VSTest task in TFS 2015 vNext build definition to run with Visual Studio 2017.

You didn't say what the specific problems were, but the problem I ran into was that the Visual Studio Test task was using an older VSTest version (from Visual Studio 2015 in my case) which by default wasn't detecting the unit tests in my test project that uses the newer [.NET Core project format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj) along with the [MSTest.TestAdapter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestAdapter/) NuGet package.

The solution I found was under the Visual Studio Test task's "Advanced Execution Options" section to set "Path to Custom Test Adapters" to `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` so that it could find the `MSTest.TestAdapter` assemblies that end up in the `bin` directory.